# Runtime resolution of destinations within Spring and JMS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-jms

I am trying to dynamically resolve;

```
@JmsListener(destinations = "${some.key}")
```

Now I know we can resolve this using properties using such thing as PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

I have found the following spring ticket, https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12289. Which gives me some indication that this can be done without the use of properties files using a DestinationResolver. I am hoping that this is a resolver that is not property based but I am not 100% sure. Could some give me an example of this without using xml based spring.

Comment: A DestinationResolver does not resolve properties in  spring config files. It resolves a logical JMS destination name to the physical destination. For example given a queue name jms.queue.order it might be resolved to either a dynamic queue or a queue retrieved from JNDI using the name. DestinationResolver works similar to ViewResolver in Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated-support) which shows how to configure a custom destination resolver in the listener container factory that generates the listener for the annotation:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
    return factory;
}
```